# How do I get count(*) from table where cond1=$cond1 and cond2=$cond2 real-time

Tags: sql, database

guys:

Assuming that I have a base table, which records tuples. If users want to get the count(*) satisfying some conditions, they can use SQL query like this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table where cond1=$cond1 AND cond2 = $cond2 AND...
```

Question 1: If the condition keeps the same, how can we get the real-time count? for some reason that I can not use count(*) directly to fullfill the task.

Question 2: If new condition occurs, how to extend the case in question 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Although it's hard to imagine what exactly can prevent you from using `COUNT()` one possible way of achieving your goal (if I understand your requirements correctly) and assuming that number of possible combination of parameters are limited, might be:

   - Creating a table that keeps counts for different sets of conditions
   - Creating trigger(s) on the base table that repopulate(s)/recalculate(s) count values on update, insert, delete operations
   - Reading counts from that table
2. Update your triggers

Comment: add trigger I need contact database admin and he said it's hard to maintain it. How about add a table that keep count? But I care data consistency.

Comment: if you need real time counts then I believe you're out of options then. if latency is not a problem then you can use a stored procedure which will repopulate(s)/recalculate(s) count values and a scheduler to periodically run that SP.